# swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sudo

I have the latest Debian:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

I have tried following code from [this website](https://fostips.com/create-remove-swap-file-debian/):

```sh
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=4096 bs=1MiB
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
sudo swapon --show
```

After `swapon /swapfile` I get this error:

> swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument

Comment: Is the filesystem compressed? Is the disk relatively full? Try swapon's `-v` option.

Answer (score 0):

sed -i "$a/swapfile    none    swap    sw    0    0" /etc/fstab
swapoff -a
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=$swap count=1024
chmod 600 /swapfile
mkswap /swapfile
swapon -a
free -h
sysctl vm.swappiness=$swappiness
swap partition is faster though, or swap on vram.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if grep -q "/swapfile" /etc/fstab

then

echo "Flag exists"

else

sed -i "$a/swapfile    none    swap    sw    0    0" /etc/fstab

fi

swapoff -a

dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=$swap count=1024

chmod 600 /swapfile

mkswap /swapfile

swapon -a

free -h
sysctl vm.swappiness=$swappiness

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).